# Why is using a while loop better?

Tags: python

I am making a program that uses a loop to run forever and I have a snippet of code below to show you how I acheive the loop. This is just an example and not the actual program. It is the same idea though.

```
import time
def start():
    print "hello"
    time.sleep(0.2)
    start()
start()
```

All of my programmer friends tell me not to do this, and use a while loop instead. Like this:

```
import time
def start():
    while True:
        print "Hello"
        time.sleep(0.2)
start()
```

Why should I use the while loop instead when both methods work perfectly fine?

Comment: Does the recursive method actually "work fine"? Don't you get an error about max recursion depth rather quickly?

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion that neither approach is better, but there is a third approach involving lazy evaluation that can only be speculated upon until we have more of the code. #justsaying

Comment: @kojiro isn't that just complicating things? he merely 'seems' to want to run an infinite loop with some sleep (as a throttling parameter). I don't get why lazy eval is required in this scenario?

Comment: @SrikarAppal I could be off base. It's just a suspicion.

Comment: Your first approach might be a viable option in a truly functional language where tail call optimizations are performed. Since python neither is a functional language nor does tail call optimizations, it will fail. Had the optimization been done, both approaches would be more or less equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each time you are recursing, you are pushing a frame context onto your program stack. Soon you would have used up your entire allotted stack space causing stackoverflow, no pun intended ;)

The second approach has no such flaws. Hence by the looks of it 2nd is better than 1st  approach (unless more of the program is presented).

Comment: The pun is certainly intended, just not by you. :P

Answer (score 2):

If you run the program continuously with the recursion, you will get `RuntimeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 8, in <module>
    start()
  File "t.py", line 7, in start
    start()
  File "t.py", line 7, in start
    start()
  ...
  File "t.py", line 7, in start
    start()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

---

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrecursionlimit()
1000
```

Comment: You could also set the recursion limit higher to with sys.setrecursionlimit()

Comment: not a good idea to inc. recursion limit. since you are running this indefinitely, you will sooner or rather hit the limit, causing program crash...

Answer (score 1):

the while loop amd recursion both have their advantages and disadvantages but while loop is just a test and conditional jump. wheras ecursion involves pushing a stack frame, jumping, returning, and popping back from the stack.So they might have preferred while loop :)

Comment: ofcourse, testing and jumping would be more fast when compared to the steps involved in recursion.So it will be less CPU intensive

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have [Tail Call Optimization (TCO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and cannot elide the stack. As such, recursion should *not* be used for an *unbound depth* (in languages without TCO) lest you get a stack-overflow error!

While the current code might appear to be fine, consider this simple change which will quickly reveal a problem.

```
def start():
    print "hello"
    # let's go faster! -- time.sleep(0.2)
    start()
start()
```

Comment: I see no difference with the exception of the comment. What is the change?

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy the comment.

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy It runs much faster - that is, instead of only recursing 5 times a second, it might recurse 50000 times per second (and will very quickly fail).

Comment: See, that is why I have the time.sleep(), first off, I have a slow computer, so it uses less processing power, and it doesn't cause immediate stack overflow and or crash my computer.

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy Recursion should *not* be used for an unbound depth as shown in this case. The sleep doesn't matter and having it only hides the problem with this approach.

Comment: That is sorta what I meant. I probably should have reworded it.